# Checking if user is Site Owner or Site Admin in Liferay Velocity Theme

Tags: liferay, velocity

We have a theme with the following code:

```
#foreach($role in $user.getRoles())
        #if($role.getName() != "Administrator")
        <style>
            header.portlet-topper{pointer-events: none;}
            header.portlet-topper > .portlet-topper-toolbar > span{pointer-events: all;}
            header.portlet-topper > .portlet-topper-toolbar > a{pointer-events: all;}
            .aui-toolbar .add-content{display: none;}
            .aui-toolbar .manage-content{display: none;}
            .aui-toolbar .toggle-controls{display: none;}   
            .aui-toolbar .aui-toolbar-separator{display: none;}
            .portlet-topper-toolbar .portlet-close{display: none;}

            body.private-page header.portlet-topper{pointer-events: all;}
            body.private-page header.portlet-topper > .portlet-topper-toolbar > span{pointer-events: all;}
            body.private-page header.portlet-topper > .portlet-topper-toolbar > a{pointer-events: all;}
            body.private-page .aui-toolbar .add-content{display: inline;}
            body.private-page .aui-toolbar .manage-content{display: inline;}
            body.private-page .aui-toolbar .toggle-controls{display: inline;}   
            body.private-page .aui-toolbar .aui-toolbar-separator{display: inline;}
            body.private-page .portlet-topper-toolbar .portlet-close{display: inline;}

        </style>
        #end
        #if($role.getName() == "Administrator")
        <style>
            header.portlet-topper{pointer-events: all;}
            header.portlet-topper > .portlet-topper-toolbar > span{pointer-events: all;}
            header.portlet-topper > .portlet-topper-toolbar > a{pointer-events: all;}
            .aui-toolbar .add-content{display: inline;}
            .aui-toolbar .manage-content{display: inline;}
            .aui-toolbar .toggle-controls{display: inline;} 
            .aui-toolbar .aui-toolbar-separator{display: inline;}
            .portlet-topper-toolbar .portlet-close{display: inline;}                
        </style>
            #break
#end
```

Basically, if the user isn't a portal admin, we take away the "Add" and "Manage" buttons on the dockbar, as well as the ability to drag/drop and remove portlets from the page. The problem is that if a user creates a new site, we want them to have those functions back. Is there a way in Velocity to tell if the user is site owner or site administrator? I've given the user the roles in the control panel for the site.

I've also tried:

```
$role.getName() == "Site Owner"
```

and

```
role.getName().equals("Site Owner")
```

but neither of these work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get the `role` in the theme:

```
#set($roleLocalService = $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.RoleLocalService"))
#set($site_owner_role = $roleLocalService.getRole($company_id, "Site Owner"))
```

Then get the `UserLocalService`

```
#set($UserLocalService =  $serviceLocator.findService("com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalService"))
```

After that you can test if the user has the `role` by doing:

```
#if ($UserLocalService.hasRoleUser($site_owner_role.getRoleId(), $user_id))
   //if the user has role...do this
#end
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. I'm not super familiar with velocity and I'm on a tight deadline. Are the objects ($serviceLocator, $roleLocalService, $company_id) already defined by default? Or do I have to get those?

Comment: Have a look here to find out which `objects `and `run time variables` are available from `velocity`,  https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Access+Objects+from+Velocity

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution did the trick. I didn't realize a lot of that stuff was defined at $init.